# Mixed strategy Nash Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

How do I solve this problem by using mixed strategy Nash equilibrium?

\begin{pmatrix}
(2,0)& (1,1)&(4,2)\\
(3,4)&(1,2)&(2,3)\\
(1,3)&(0,2)&(3,0)
\end{pmatrix}

I tried to compute the expected value of every row, but I did not get a solution for the probabilities

Answer (score 1):

It is quite clear that row strategy 1 dominates row strategy 3. Hence, row player will always pick up row1 as BR over row3. Now, eliminating row 3, the 2 by 3 matrix indicates that column 2 is dominated by column 3. This will reduce the matrix to the size of 2 by 2. Now you can calculate PSNE and MSNE[image]